# Android studio error

Tags: command-line, android

when i try to launch android studio bu terminal using the file studio.sh all went well and the program is on but i see these line

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
Error Loading DDMS Preferences
```

all it's ok or I have to do something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the directory where you have Android Studio. Then go to the `bin/` subdirectory. Locate the following files, which contains Java Virtual Machine options:

- `studio.vmoptions`
- `studio64.vmoptions`

Open these files and locate line with `MaxPerSize` parameter. It should look as follows:

`XX:MaxPermSize=256m`

Remove this line in both files. I don't know if you are using 32-bit or 64-bit operating system, so you can update both files just in case.

I'm not sure if it will solve your problem, but I would try it in such situation. In my case, with this option and Java 8, I just get the warning, but Android Studio starts anyway. After removing this parameter, Android Studio still starts, but without warning. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

**EDIT**:

There is another solution for this problem described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27913562/1150795.

Go to **File > Other Settings > Default Project Structure > JDK location** and check the path.

In case of Ubuntu Linux, we can set `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle` as default JDK if we are using Oracle JVM. JDK 7 is the safest option for Android.

Comment: can u tell me why I had this problem?

Comment: you had it in your error log: `support was removed in 8.0`. JDK8 made some changes for which Android Studio with Gradle was not prepared :-D